# android.widget.TextView becomes null?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

in my Fragment.onCreateView(inflater), I keep a reference to a widge:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shipping, container, false);
...
        mMyBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.mybtn);
```

So I can use it later:

```
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
...
        mMyBtn.setEnabled(false);
```

Somehow, I get nullpointer in mMyBtn.setEnabled reported in Firebase Crashlytics occasionally (100% Android 8 devices).

Question:  did I do it wrong in the wrong lifecycle callback? i.e., instead of keep the widget reference in **onCreateView(...)**, should I do it in **onViewCreated(...)**?  I have been doing this way forever wondering if I am out of dated ...

Any suggestion, to make my code more defensive?